# PHP "Kill" all characters from string except A-Z and ";"

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$string='A;B;C;1;2-;D'
```

how can i remove all characters from this the string above but keep the Letters and the ";"

Comment: Have you even tried to use search engine? Just try "remove" instead of "kill", soldier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple regex:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Z;]+/', '', $string);
```

or

```
 preg_replace('/[^A-Z;]+/i', '', $string);
```

If you need case insensitive.

Comment: @TheMasta: If it works for you, feel free to accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
 $repl = preg_replace('/[^a-z;]+/i', '', $str);
```

`^a-z;` inside square brackets (character class) means match anything but English letters `a-z` (range) OR a semi-colon `;`

`/i` is for ignore case to avoid matching uppercase/lowercase english letters.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 preg_match('/[^a-z;]/i', $string);
```